# How to define relationships when using interfaces

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, laravel-5

The normal use of polymorphic relationships in Laravel is covered pretty well by the Post--User--Image example.

I'm trying to find a clean way to implement relationships for let's say an Article/ContentA/ContentB relationship.

```
articles
  id

content_1
  id

content_2
  id

user_defined_content_n
  id

contentables
  article_id
  contentable_id
  contentable_type // content_2, user_defined_content_n
```

The content classes are not necessarily known by the article, so defining the article model with many `MorphedByMany` relationships is not how I want to do this.

Perhaps I am structuring my classes poorly. I could create a `ContentEntity` class which morphs to individual `Content` classes but I would like to avoid this if possible.

---

Maybe this better explains my problem.

```php
class Article extends Model {
    public function contentEntities() {
        return $this->hasMany(ContentEntity::class);
    }
}

class ContentEntity extends Model {
    public function contentable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Content extends Model {
    public function contentEntity() {
        return $this->morphOne(ContentEntity::class, 'contentable');
    }
}

class Video extends Model {
    public function contentEntity() {
        $this->morphOne(ContentEntity::class, 'contentable');
    }
}
```

This works but seems very unclean to me. I think it adds too much developer overhead to have to manage the `ContentEntity` parent.

**Edit:**
Unless someone provides a better solution, I went with an EAV style solution using `ContentEntity`s.

Comment: Please post some code, your `article`, `contentA` and `contentB`

Comment: @MohamedKawsara I think the table I've added should help clarify my question.

Comment: I have flagged this to have it moved to programmers exchange since it's a bit off topic for SO

Comment: If you don't want to use `MorphedByMany` then r u saying u have dynamic models? and you are creating tables for these models dynamically too?

Comment: content_1 and content_2 they have more or less the same structure? if you had to describe those tables in code would you say that exist an abstact table content and content_1 extends content and content_2 as well?

Comment: @borracciaBlu I will update the question using another example to try to clarify this more.

Answer (score 1):

You could always extract the relationship to a trait for easier maintenance and extendability in the future:

**Trait**

```
trait Contentable
{
    public function contentEntity() {
        if(property_exists($this, 'contentable') && $contentable == 'many') {
            return $this->hasMany(ContentEntity::class);
        } else {
            return $this->morphOne(ContentEntity::class, 'contentable');
        }
    }

    // Future implementations
}
```

Then all you need to do is use the trait in various entities:

**Models**

```
class Content extends Model {
    use Contentable;
}

class Video extends Model {
    use Contentable;
}

class Article extends Model {
    use Contentable;

    protected $contentable = 'many';
}
```